# Reverse engineer serial data packet

Tags: serial-port, protocols, reverse-engineering

i have a device connected to PC vie serial port (rs-232).
That device send data after receiving command from serial port, i sniffed data flows throught port and almost completely found out packet structure, but at least two important fields i cant determine.

First example packet (in hex) - 2 payload packets inside:

```
0baa00000200039540330137732904020033000005534d6c07a567a73e15040701125600043853048a5c085500000000e940406f00039540330058388900020033000005534d6c07b501b4f01504070113020004fd1d040342155500000000e940406f0002009d0a03004a3030313733353530303830343630303830373131313030323415040701210801001035390000000000000000d3a7226c287472874b2a216a000000000000000000ab04
```

Second example packet (in hex) - 6 payload packets inside:

```
0b6601000600039540330137732904020033000005534d6c07a567a73e15040701125600043853048a5c085500000000e940406f00039540330058388900020033000005534d6c07b501b4f01504070113020004fd1d040342155500000000e940406f00039540330137732904020033000005534d6c07a567a73e15040702174901043853048a5c085500000000e940406f00039540330058388900020033000005534d6c07b501b4f01504070218010104fd1d040342155500000000e940406f00039540330137732904020033000005534d6c07a567a73e15040703301002043853048a5c085500000000e940406f00039540330058388900020033000005534d6c07b501b4f01504070331280204fd1d040342155500000000e940406f000600a10a03004a303031373335353030383034363030383037313131303032341504071152520100103539000000000000000094b5d2c94a11672acaa0abec0000000000000000006a85
```

Packet structure that i determined (first packet as example):
[image: Packet structure]

Fileds marked as ??? - i dont know what is it and need to guess.
Payload data packets may be vary count.
If i edit any byte from inside packets and recalculate last CRC16, programm will accept packet, but with message that its corrupted. If i edit any byte without CRC16 recalculation, program will reject that packet.

What i need from that? For example, i need to edit - add or delete some inside payload data packets.

I will be very appreciate for any help.

**UPDATE 1**

Two same packets with different request time field:

```
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

0b6601000600039540330137732904020033000005534d6c07a567a73e15040701125600043853048a5c085500000000e940406f00039540330058388900020033000005534d6c07b501b4f01504070113020004fd1d040342155500000000e940406f00039540330137732904020033000005534d6c07a567a73e15040702174901043853048a5c085500000000e940406f00039540330058388900020033000005534d6c07b501b4f01504070218010104fd1d040342155500000000e940406f00039540330137732904020033000005534d6c07a567a73e15040703301002043853048a5c085500000000e940406f00039540330058388900020033000005534d6c07b501b4f01504070331280204fd1d040342155500000000e940406f000600a10a03004a303031373335353030383034363030383037313131303032341504071152520100103539000000000000000094b5d2c94a11672acaa0abec0000000000000000006a85
```

Comment: What exactly is it that you are asking for help with? Do you want help figuring out what the mysterious fields are? You have an interesting question with plenty of work shown, but I'm not sure that Stack Overflow is the place to ask for help with this sort of thing.

Comment: Thank you for reply, Im asking for help to determine what may be the fields: second and third bytes from the start (ex. aa00; 6601) and last 14 bytes before last zeros sequense.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot shed much light on this, but I can offer this much.

Each packet you have shown appears to have the following layout:

```
<start><length><data><zeros><checksum>
```

Where:

- `<start>` is 1 byte (`0b`).
- `<length>` is 2 bytes (`aa00` and `6601`). This is the size of `<data>`, in little endian (0x00AA is 170, 0x0166 is 358).
- `<data>` begins with a 2-byte item count (`0002` and `0006`), in big endian (0x0002 is 2, 0x0006 is 6), and the rest of the content mostly follows your analysis.
- `<zeros>` is a variable length block of `00` bytes.
- `<checksum>` is 2 bytes.

The packets you have shown would thus break down like this:

```
0b
aa00
  0002
    0003954033 0137732904 020033000005534d6c07 a567a73e 150407 011256 0004 3853048a5c08 5500000000e940406f
    0003954033 0058388900 020033000005534d6c07 b501b4f0 150407 011302 0004 fd1d04034215 5500000000e940406f
  0002 009d 0a0300 4a303031373335 35303038303436303038303731313130303234 150407 012108 0100103539 0000000000000000 d3a7226c287472874b2a216a
000000000000000000
ab04
```

```
0b
6601
  0006
    0003954033 0137732904 020033000005534d6c07 a567a73e 150407 011256 0004 3853048a5c08 5500000000e940406f
    0003954033 0058388900 020033000005534d6c07 b501b4f0 150407 011302 0004 fd1d04034215 5500000000e940406f
    0003954033 0137732904 020033000005534d6c07 a567a73e 150407 021749 0104 3853048a5c08 5500000000e940406f
    0003954033 0058388900 020033000005534d6c07 b501b4f0 150407 021801 0104 fd1d04034215 5500000000e940406f
    0003954033 0137732904 020033000005534d6c07 a567a73e 150407 033010 0204 3853048a5c08 5500000000e940406f
    0003954033 0058388900 020033000005534d6c07 b501b4f0 150407 033128 0204 fd1d04034215 5500000000e940406f
  0006 00a1 0a0300 4a303031373335 35303038303436303038303731313130303234 150407 115252 0100103539 0000000000000000 94b5d2c94a11672acaa0abec 00000000
0000000000
6a85
```

You will notice that in the second packet, there are extra `00` bytes at the end of `<data>`, and `<zeros>` is smaller than the first packet.  If those extra `00` bytes were moved down to `<zeros>`, both packets would have 9 bytes in `<zeros>`:

```
0b
aa00
  0002
    0003954033 0137732904 020033000005534d6c07 a567a73e 150407 011256 0004 3853048a5c08 5500000000e940406f
    0003954033 0058388900 020033000005534d6c07 b501b4f0 150407 011302 0004 fd1d04034215 5500000000e940406f
  0002 009d 0a0300 4a303031373335 35303038303436303038303731313130303234 150407 012108 0100103539 0000000000000000 d3a7226c287472874b2a216a
000000000000000000
ab04
```

```
0b
6601
  0006
    0003954033 0137732904 020033000005534d6c07 a567a73e 150407 011256 0004 3853048a5c08 5500000000e940406f
    0003954033 0058388900 020033000005534d6c07 b501b4f0 150407 011302 0004 fd1d04034215 5500000000e940406f
    0003954033 0137732904 020033000005534d6c07 a567a73e 150407 021749 0104 3853048a5c08 5500000000e940406f
    0003954033 0058388900 020033000005534d6c07 b501b4f0 150407 021801 0104 fd1d04034215 5500000000e940406f
    0003954033 0137732904 020033000005534d6c07 a567a73e 150407 033010 0204 3853048a5c08 5500000000e940406f
    0003954033 0058388900 020033000005534d6c07 b501b4f0 150407 033128 0204 fd1d04034215 5500000000e940406f
  0006 00a1 0a0300 4a303031373335 35303038303436303038303731313130303234 150407 115252 0100103539 0000000000000000 94b5d2c94a11672acaa0abec
000000000000000000
6a85
```

But then the second packet's `<length>` would be wrong, as it would have to be `5C01` instead of `6601`.

Much deeper analysis is needed to figure out this descrepency, and to know whether those `00` bytes have meaning where they are originally located based on `<length>`, as well as all of the other known fields.

Comment: Thank you for that analysis, the size of each block i determined before question and these packets are original from device and program accepts them as correct. One thing that i can add, that if i'll request from device same information different times - the last DATE and TIME will be the time when i request data, all fields till "d3a7226c287472874b2a216a" (14 unique bytes from end) will be the same. I think its a kind of hash which starts from, may be, device name block and at least differ packet time gives differ sequence of these 14 bytes.

Comment: I think if i could understand the algo of these bytes i could make the correct packet. I dont need to make whole packets from scratch, i need only take information from device, edit it (add, delete inside payload) and send it to program. I want to say, that i dont need to reverse all bytes, because some of them static from device (such as "0b"). Mb <start><length><data><zeros><checksum> -> can be <start><length><data><zeros><HASH or ???><zeros><checksum>?

Comment: Now im trying at least change seconds in packet request time filed, to determine the algo of 14 bytes, but if ill change it by myself, program will say about corrupted data. i have two identicial packets, with same payload and etc, but they different in request time field, maybe, it will help you to help me to find the algo. I added packets in the question UPDATE 1.

Comment: There is no way to identify the hash algorithm being used (if it even is a hash) just by looking at the raw bytes. I suggest you find out what type of device is sending this data and then contact the manufacturer directly and ask for details about this protocol.

Comment: Manufacturer refuses requests about protocol... In overview for some other devices from that manufacturer presents information that them using DLMS/COSEM communication standard (and some words about something like HDLC and x.25), but im not sure about my device, there is no such specification. P.S. Maybe its not a hash, but FCS (Frame Check Sequence)?

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of a thing where unless your time is almost free, you just go and buy the specifications. If you have a couple thousand USD to lay out, you should definitely become a member of DLMS-UA (their User Association) and that way you get access to the so-called "colored books" - the "ground truth" standards of the DLMS organization itself.

The excerpts from the colored books are [freely available](https://www.dlms.com/resources/coloured-books-extracts). Those should cover some of the basics.

The core books of interest would be the Blue Book and the Green Book, and those are "opened up" to non-members via the ISO/IEC standardization process. Quoting the [DLMS International Standardization page](https://www.dlms.com/dlms-cosem/international-standardization), the relevant international standards are:

> - [IEC 62056-5-3](https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/27065), DLMS/COSEM application layer. Edition 3.0 (2017) is in line with Green Book Edition 8.3;
> - [IEC 62056-6-2](https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/34317), COSEM interface classes. Edition 3.0, (2017) is in line with Blue Book Edition 12.2;
> - [IEC 62056-6-1](https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/32782), OBIS Object identification system Edition 3.0, (2017) is in line with Blue Book Edition 12.2.

[X.25](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.25-199610-I/) is an open ITU recommendation.

The very basics of HDLC framing are explained in [IETF RFC1662 PPP in HDLC-like Framing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1662).